# Wordpress Taxonomy Term not accepting dymanic varialble

Tags: arrays, wordpress, taxonomy

I have this code.

$activity = 79, 71, 78, 74, 77, 76, 75, 73;

**Is working**

```
$args = array(
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'showposts' => '-1',
            'post_type' => 'packages',
                'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => "activity",
                        'terms' => array(79, 71, 78, 74, 77, 76, 75, 73), // working
                        'field' => 'id'                  
                    ),
                     array(
                        'taxonomy' => "destination",
                        'terms' => "$destination",
                        'field' => 'id'                  
                    )
                )
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if($query->have_posts() ) :   ?>
```

**Is Not working**

```
$args = array(
            'orderby' => 'rand',
            'showposts' => '-1',
            'post_type' => 'packages',
                'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => "activity",
                        'terms' => array($activity), // Variable not working
                        'field' => 'id'                  
                    ),
                     array(
                        'taxonomy' => "destination",
                        'terms' => "$destination",
                        'field' => 'id'                  
                    )
                )
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            if($query->have_posts() ) :   ?>
```

When i put variable inside the array it deesnot work. Can Anyone has any sugestion ??

Answer (score 0):

Set:

```
$activity = array(79, 71, 78, 74, 77, 76, 75, 73);
```

Then you can use:

```
'terms' => $activity,
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didnt help. the numbers that i provided are just predefine. I want to save numbers in array that numbers will be generated dynamically. and use that array of numbers on terms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your variable like this:-

```
$activity = '79, 71, 78, 74, 77, 76, 75, 73';
$new_activity = explode(',', $activity);
```

And in the query:-

```
'terms' => $new_activity,
```

Hope this will help you...